# sndPlaySound or PlaySound on KeyPress - Playing keyboard sounds

Tags: delphi, playsound

I am trying to make a program that plays sound files on every keypress in TEdit.

I tried sndPlaySound from a resource file on a Edit1 KeyPress event, but the problem is that it does not exactly play sounds as if in real keyboard typing. There's a delay in sound playing between every key pressed.

```
procedure TForm2.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
sndPlaySound(PCHAR('KeyPress'), SND_RESOURCE OR SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

This code does play sounds, but if you type quickly, only on the last key you type you'd hear the sound file being played.

Comment: I don't think you'll ever make this by using Windows API. I would suggest you to use some specialized audio library, like for instance [`Bass`](http://www.un4seen.com/) audio library.

Comment: Can you please provide me a working example of how to use Bass to achieve what I described in my question?

Comment: Uhm, that's what you could try to do yourself. StackOverflow is not a *"write the code for me, please"* service. But well, since it's easy, I'll make an exception; try a code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/zFww00ra). Just don't forget to download the [`library itself`](http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?bass24), and from that archive make the `Bass.pas` unit visible to your project's search path and `Bass.dll` to the project's output. Note, that it's not the only audio library available for use in Delphi and I don't want to favour it. It was just the first one on top of my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer posted by TLama is this code which worked perfectly well:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
Dialogs, StdCtrls, Bass;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
Edit1: TEdit;
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
private
StreamHandle: HSTREAM;
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, Handle, nil) then
begin
StreamHandle := BASS_StreamCreateFile(False, PChar('c:\Windows\Media\tada.wav'), 0,
  0, 0 {$IFDEF UNICODE} or BASS_UNICODE {$ENDIF});
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
BASS_StreamFree(StreamHandle);
BASS_Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
BASS_ChannelPlay(StreamHandle, True);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the WAVEOUT interface, but I believe this delay is some detail in the code that must be corrected. try to use the parameter SND_FILENAME.

the api is appropriate for what you're trying to do.